# convert InstanceContextMode.Single to InstanceContextMode.PerCall

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have a WCF service that takes 5 min to load everything from a database. I want to get the best performance out of WCF and found this article http://theburningmonk.com/2010/05/wcf-improve-performance-with-greater-concurrency/
it states i will get better performance using PerCall. I have anywhere between 2000 and 4000 hits per second.

my problem is it takes a long time to load the data. per the article it's saying create a wrapper to the real service using a static variable.
i am not sure how that looks and i have no idea what _container really is.
Any chance someone can give me a full example of the below?

> In cases where the initialization steps are lengthy and unavoidable, or your class require a number of parameters in the constructor (for instance, when you programmatically host a service retrieve from an IoC container) the parameterless constructor can become a problem. To get around this, you could create a wrapper for your class and expose the wrapper as the service instead but hold a static instance of the underlying service which all the requests are passed on to:

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]
public class MyServiceWrapper : IMyServiceWrapper
{
    // get the underlying service from the container
    private static IMyService MyService = _container.Resolve<IMyService>();


public MyServiceWrapper()
{
    // parameterless constructor which does nothing, so easy to constructor
}
public void DoSomething()
{
    MyService.DoSomething();
}
```

}

```
// dummy interface to ensure the wrapper has the same methods as the underlying service
// but helps to avoid confusion
public interface IMyServiceWrapper : IMyService
{
}
```

> For a sessionful service, the PerSession instance context mode gives
>   you all the benefit of the PerCall instance context mode and at the
>   same time reduces the overhead you pay for that extra concurrency
>   because new instances of your class are no longer created for each
>   request but for each session instead.

Comment: I guess _container here is for IOC container, and the line of code is trying to resolve the instance for the IMyService. If you are not using IOC container, you can just return the instance of your service.

Comment: so all that wrapper stuff can just be ignored and i can just do this?

  [ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple,
        InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall,
        AddressFilterMode = AddressFilterMode.Any)]
    public class DialPlan : IDialPlan
    {
        internal static SonicSBCRouting s =null;
        public DialPlan()
        {
            Start();

        }
      
       
 

        public void Start()
        {    if(s==null)
             s = new SonicSBCRouting();
         
   s.Startup();

        }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the logic of fetching service object from IOC container:

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]
    public class MyServiceWrapper : IMyServiceWrapper
    {
        // get the underlying service from the container
        private static IMyService myService = new MyService();


        public MyServiceWrapper()
        {
            // parameterless constructor which does nothing, so easy to constructor
        }
        public void DoSomething()
        {
            myService.DoSomething();
        }
    }

    // dummy interface to ensure the wrapper has the same methods as the underlying service
    // but helps to avoid confusion
    public interface IMyServiceWrapper : IMyService
    {
    }
```